# SQL: Removing Duplicates rows while retaining the row with highest value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, duplicates, sql-delete

Suppose i have a table Test with Data:

```
SOID SO_Name   SO_Desc     PRIORITY  ADE_PRIORITIZED  DEPLOY_DATE  ENV
123  SO1      SO1 Desc1      111      Y               01-JAN-01     0
123  SO1      SO1 Desc1      111      Y               01-JAN-01     1
123  SO1      SO1 Desc1      111      Y               01-JAN-01     2
123  SO1      SO1 Desc1      111      Y               01-JAN-01     3
987  SO1      SO1 Desc1      111      Y               01-JAN-01     0
987  SO1      SO1 Desc1      111      Y               01-JAN-16     1
987  SO1      SO1 Desc1      111      Y               21-JAN-17     2
987  SO1      SO1 Desc1      111      Y               01-JAN-17     3
121  SO121    SO121 Desc121  111      Y               01-JAN-17     0
```

I want to remove the duplicate rows for each soid (duplicate can be based on the 4 columns: so_name,so_desc,priority, ade_prioritized) retaining the row with highest deploy_date.

I used this query but it doesn't delete any row.

```
delete from so_test a 
where a.deploy_date < (
  select max(b.deploy_date) from so_test b where a.soid = b.soid
);

0 rows deleted
```

The end result i expect should be:
SOID SO_Name   SO_Desc     PRIORITY  ADE_PRIORITIZED  DEPLOY_DATE  ENV
123  SO1      SO1 Desc1      111      Y               01-JAN-01     0
987  SO1      SO1 Desc1      111      Y               21-JAN-17     2
987  SO1      SO1 Desc1      111      Y               21-JAN-17     2

What can be the issue? 
can it be done without CTE?

Comment: Given that data, zero rows will be deleted, because zero rows match the criteria.  For SOID=123, all the Deploy Dates are the same... so none is less than the max.  For SOID=121 there's only one row, so none is less than the max.

Comment: You can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) and Row_Number() to do what you want... but what's that "ENV" column over there?  Why aren't you just deleting where ENV > 0?

Comment: You tagged this with mysql, sql server, and oracle.  Which is it?

Comment: @pmbAustin - i have edited it. Now can you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example based on preserving non duplicates into a new table.

```
create table so_test_nodups 
as
with dups as 
( select soid, so_name, so_desc, priority, ade_prioritized, deploy_date, env,  
        row_number() over ( partition by so_name, so_desc, priority, ade_prioritized order by deploy_date desc ) rn 
  from so_test 
) 
select  soid, so_name, so_desc, priority, ade_prioritized, deploy_date, env 
from dups 
where rn=1
```

Querying the so_test_nodups table.

```
select * from so_test_nodups

      SOID SO_NAME    SO_DESC                PRIORITY A DEPLOY_DA        ENV
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- - --------- ----------
       123 SO1        SO1 Desc1                   111 Y 01-JAN-01          0
       121 SO121      SO121 Desc121               111 Y 01-JAN-17          0
```

Adding the results after the edits provided:

```
      SOID SO_NAME    SO_DESC                PRIORITY A DEPLOY_DA        ENV
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- - --------- ----------
       987 SO1        SO1 Desc1                   111 Y 21-JAN-17          2
       121 SO121      SO121 Desc121               111 Y 01-JAN-17          0
```

Comment: Thanks Bob. I have edited it, can you check now? Also i need to delete from same table and use that table only.

Comment: After creating the so_test_nodups, just drop so_test and rename so_test_nodups to so_test.

Comment: I ran it with edited data (can see above, it has 987 as soid) but its not paiking the highest deploy_date row.

Comment: @Mishti  I have added a new set of results based upon you latest test data. See above.

Answer (score 1):

Using  [**`with (common table expression)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) you can both identify and then easily handle duplicates:

When using a ctes, you can only perform one statement after the expression (unless you are chaining ctes or using multiple ctes).

In the following code example you would first check the output by using the select, then if further actions are necessary, comment out the select query and un-comment the delete query.

rextester link: http://rextester.com/UFQQ51693

```
with cte as (
  select   
      *
    , rn = row_number() over (
            partition by soid 
            order by deploy_date desc
            )
    from [so_test]
)
/* --------------------------------------------------------------
-- This returns all of rows with values that have duplicates
-- along the row number (rn) so you can see which rows 
-- would be affected by the following actions
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*
select o.*
  from cte as o
  where exists (
      select 1
        from cte as i
        where cte.soid  = i.soid 
          and i.rn>1
      );
--*/
/* --------------------------------------------------------------
-- Remove duplicates by deleting all of the duplicates
-- where the row number (rn) is greater than 1
-- without deleting the first row of the duplicates.
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
--/*
delete 
  from cte 
  where cte.rn > 1 
--*/
```

rextester reults after delete:

```
+------+---------+---------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+-----+
| soid | so_name |    so_desc    | priority | ade_prioritized |     deploy_date     | env |
+------+---------+---------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+-----+
|  123 | SO1     | SO1_Desc1     |      111 | Y               | 01.01.2001 00:00:00 |   0 |
|  987 | SO1     | SO1_Desc1     |      111 | Y               | 21.01.2017 00:00:00 |   2 |
|  121 | SO121   | SO121_Desc121 |      111 | Y               | 01.01.2017 00:00:00 |   0 |
+------+---------+---------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+-----+
```

Comment: If you have a large number of duplicates, it may be faster or more efficient to create a new table with the non-duplicated rows, rather than deleting the duplicated rows. Using the CTE and row_number() functions shown by @sqlzim, you can do a CREATE TABLE as SELECT... (CTAS) or INSERT as SELECT. Then you can employ parallelism and direct path loading to get maximum performance.

Comment: I have never used CTE so not sure how it can be done. Is there any other way other tan CTE. i understand that here all deploy dates are same for a SOID so its not deleting. But there could be case where all dates are same and then 1 row needs to be retained and if deply_date is different then max nddeploy date should be retained and if only 1 row that should be retained.

Comment: @Mishti I think you should learn how to use the CTE. I added a rextester link so you can try it out.

Comment: @sqlZim- I am getting this error when i run CTE statement:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 82 Column: 5

I am using sqldeveloper64